# Android Virtual Device(AVD) creation issue on Arch

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create AVD in my Arch machine. I am using Android Studio. While i'am going to create AVD it showing "An error occurred while creating the AVD. See idea.log for details". I couldn't found anything at log file.

Last few line generated at log file while creating AVD:

```
2017-11-01 21:16:31,412 [3170173]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon2-1.xml 
2017-11-01 21:16:31,645 [3170406]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon2-1.xml 
2017-11-01 21:16:31,872 [3170633]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Downloading file:/home/aswin/Desktop/android-studio/plugins/sdk-updates/offline-repo/offline-repo.xml 
2017-11-01 21:18:12,693 [3271454]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create the SD card. 
2017-11-01 21:18:12,828 [3271589]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder. 
2017-11-01 21:19:19,823 [3338584]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create the SD card. 
2017-11-01 21:19:19,851 [3338612]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder. 
2017-11-01 21:20:42,227 [3420988]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create the SD card. 
2017-11-01 21:20:42,273 [3421034]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder. 
2017-11-01 21:23:46,799 [3605560]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create the SD card. 
2017-11-01 21:23:46,819 [3605580]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder. 
2017-11-01 22:12:36,546 [6535307]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create the SD card. 
2017-11-01 22:12:36,647 [6535408]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a 64-bit machine there are certain 32-bit C libraries that need to be specifically installed in order for AVD to be able to create the virtual device.

You'll need to install the **lib32-gcc-libs** library from the Arch core repository, as follows:

```
sudo pacman -S lib32-gcc-libs
```

Trying to create the virtual device after this package has been installed should work.

Comment: nope. Did not work for me.